# Eliminate Multiple Records In Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a select I want only one record returned for each case and am having a problem with it.

Example:

```
Select 
    CaseId, Party_id, RANKING
from...
```

The problem is at the charge level the case can have similar multiple charges...

Charges

```
    Case   ChargeCount  RANKING    
     1           1        800
     2           1        802
     2           2        803 
     3           1        800
```

I only want 3 cases returned with the first charge meeting the criteria selected.
I tried using a simple partition by over caseId but this messed up the counts elsewhere.
Is there other ways to do this???

Thanks

Comment: Show the full query instead of just giving us `from...`. The more information you give, the easier it is to help.

Comment: What rule should be enforced to select one record where there are multiples with the same `Case`?  Lowest/Highest ChargeCount/Ranking?  Flip a coin? ;)

Comment: Basically, *what* should the output be for this particular example?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT CaseId, ChargeCount, Ranking FROM SomeTable WHERE ChargeCount = 1
```

Unless I'm missing something, it's that simple. Your example query is not exactly very illuminating to the underlying structures that you have presented.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want exactly one row returned per CaseID:

```
Select 
    CaseId, Party_id, RANKING
from...
GROUP BY CaseID
```

Note that where there are multiple possible answers for each row, this will return an arbitrary one unless you define somehow the one to pick.